# Output multiple lots of data as apposed to only one

Tags: php, html, sql, database

Error

Any help you guys could give would be much appreciated,
I look forward to hearing from you, Qwerty.

Comment: I know brackets can be optional but you really should always use them. You'll be thankful later on down the road.

Comment: you should have while loop in that mess somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than

```
$don2=mysql_fetch_assoc(
    mysql_query(...
```

Try

```
$results2 = mysql_query(...
```

then do

```
while (($don2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results2)) !== false) {
    echo '<h2...
}
```

`mysql_query` sets up the query to run. `mysql_fetch_assoc` actually pulls down one row at a time. So you want to loop while there are rows remaining.

Comment: Thanks for actually taking the time to help instead of victimizing like the rest, who have nothing better to do.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much (Y).